# Karma istanbul coverage report auto-refresh upon code change in Angular

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

when I do `ng test --code-coverage` it spits out the coverage report. Now I do `ng test --watch=true` and make my changes to the spec files but the report is not auto refreshing. How to auto-refresh the coverage report which saves my development time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable auto-refresh of code-coverage report, we need to set `{"codeCoverage": true}` in "options" subsection of "test" section in angular.json. I updated my angular.json as follows `"test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "codeCoverage": true,
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        }`